# Insert nan after specific value in df - python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to insert nan into columns after a specific value in a df. Using below, where `Item == Orange`, I'm hoping to replace the subsequent rows in `'Val1','Val2'` with nan.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({      
    'Time' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4],    
    'Group' : ['A','B','A','A','B','A','A','B','A','A','B','A'],   
    'Item' : ['Red','Blue','Orange','Red','Blue','Orange','Red','Blue','Orange','Red','Blue','Orange'],
    'Val1' : [-2.0,-1.0,-1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,2.0,-1.0,0.0,0.0],
    'Val2' : [-2.0,-1.0,-2.0,-1.0,-2.0,-1.0,0.0,1.0,3.0,-2.0,-1.0,-2.0],              
   })

df.loc[df['Item'].isin(['Orange']), ['Val1','Val2']].shift(1) = np.nan
```

With my attempt above, I get a SyntaxError:

```
File "<ipython-input-11-c3d6ab463712>", line 11
    df.loc[df['Item'].isin(['Orange']), ['Val1','Val2']].shift(1) = np.nan
                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

intended output:

```
    Time Group    Item  Val1  Val2
0      1     A     Red  -2.0  -2.0
1      1     B    Blue  -1.0  -1.0
2      1     A  Orange  -1.0  -2.0
3      2     A     Red   NaN   NaN
4      2     B    Blue   0.0  -2.0
5      2     A  Orange   1.0  -1.0
6      3     A     Red   NaN   NaN
7      3     B    Blue   1.0   1.0
8      3     A  Orange   2.0   3.0
9      4     A     Red  NaN    NaN
10     4     B    Blue   0.0  -1.0
11     4     A  Orange   0.0  -2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh you're so close.

You need to rearrange things a bit and make sure your boolean mask doesn't have any NaNs in it:

```py
df.loc[df['Item'].isin(['Orange']).shift(1).fillna(False), ['Val1', 'Val2']] = np.nan
```